# Sub-classing float type in Python, fails to catch exception in __init__()

Tags: python, exception

On Python 2.5 I need to use float numbers with a modified `__str__()` method. Also I need to know when the constructor fails.

Why I can't catch exceptions raised from `float.__init__()`?

What is the best way to consult the numeric value of my derived float object? In my code I'm using `float(self)`.

```
class My_Number(float):
    def __init__(self, float_string):
        try:
            super(My_Number, self).__init__(float_string)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise My_Error(float_string)

    def __str__(self):
        if int(float(self)) == float(self):
            return str(int(float(self)))
        else:
            return str(round(float(self), 2))


>>> n = My_Number('0.54353')
>>> print n
0.54

>>> n = My_Number('5.0')
>>> print n
5

>>> n = My_Number('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): foo
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`float` is immutable, therefore its `__init__`, the **initializer**, is basically a no-op -- nothing substantial can happen there, because the `self` object cannot be altered (if it's actually an instance of `float` rather than of a subclass -- but of course `float`'s own `__init__` must operate on that assumption;-).

Therefore, all the action happens in `__new__`, the **constructor** proper, just like for other immutable types like `int`, `str`, `tuple`, and so on.  It's a common mistake to believe that `__init__` is a constructor: it's not, it takes an already-constructed object as its first argument, `self`, and "initializes" it (if feasible, i.e., if that `self` is mutable!-) -- the **construction** itself happens in `__new__`.

So, your `float` subclass should start:

```
class My_Number(float):
  def __new__(cls, float_string):
    try: return float.__new__(cls, float_string)
    except (TypeError, ValueError): raise My_Error(float_string)
```

and you can remove the `__init__`, which is not needed.  Now:

```
>>> n = My_Number('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __new__
NameError: global name 'My_Error' is not defined
```

(of course, it would work even better if you **did** have a `My_Error` exception class defined;-).

Answer (score 8):

try `__new__` instead:

```
class F(float):
    def __new__(cls, *arg, **kw):
        try:
            return float.__new__(cls, *arg, **kw)
        except ValueError:
            raise Exception("foo")

print F("3.5")            
print F("asdf")
```

Also "self" is a float already so no need to say float(self), just "self" will do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%.2f" % self
```

Comment: Thanks!, worked perfectly. About the `"%.2f" % self`, what method is used for the string conversion? `float.__str__()`? I thought it was `F.__str__()` which it isn't, because there is not infinite recursion.