# Error initializing subclass of float

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7, built-in

This is what I'm doing:

```
class D(float):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        print name
```

But when I try to initialize on object of type `D`:

```
d = D('aaa')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/untitled1.py", line 22, in <module>
    d = D('aaa')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: aaa
```

Why? I'm not initializing a float, just setting a name. I didn't call the `__init__` of float.

Comment: I've read the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936457/sub-classing-float-type-in-python-fails-to-catch-exception-in-init) and I don't think it's a duplicate. That question just want to overwrite `__str__` and I'm trying just to set a name attribute in my class. I'm trying with the `__new__` constructor but I could'n manage how to solve the problem, so I think the question is still valid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that prior to inititalizer, that is `__init__` function, a constructor, that is `__new__`, is called. It is called with the same arguments as `__init__`. As for your class it is not defined, it's superclass' one, that is `float`'s, is called, and error is raised. You can see it if you wrap constructor:

```
>>> class D(float):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print cls, args, kwargs
...         return super(D, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         print value
...
>>> D('a')
<class '__main__.D'> ('a',) {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __new__
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

If you want add custom attributes, use something like follows:

```
>>> class D(float):
...     __slots__ = ['name']
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         name = kwargs.pop('name')
...         obj = super(D, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
...         obj.name = name
...         return obj
...
>>> d = D(0, name='d')
>>> e = D(1, name='e')
>>> d, d.name
(0.0, 'd')
>>> e, e.name
(1.0, 'e')
```

Comment: So, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: @xndrme Sorry, but I saw just the question, namely "why?". What is your problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @xndrme see update, does it answer your needs?

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit difficult but it works, thanks