# Python: Can a subclass of float take extra arguments in its constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, subclass, built-in

In Python 3.4, I'd like to create a subclass of `float` -- something that can be used in math and boolean operations like a `float`, but has other custom functionality and can receive an argument at initialization that controls that functionality. (Specifically, I wanted to have a custom `__str__` and a parameter that is used in that method.)

However, I can't seem to get a subclass of `float` to have a functional two-argument constructor. Why? Is this simply a limitation on extending built-in types?

Example:

```
class Foo(float):
    def __init__(self, value, extra):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.extra = extra
```

Now if I try `Foo(1,2)` I get:

```
TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Surprisingly, my new `__init__`'s arguments are enforced too, so if I do `Foo(1)` I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'extra'
```

What's the deal here? I've done similar things with subtypes of `list` and was surprised it didn't work on `float`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936457/sub-classing-float-type-in-python-fails-to-catch-exception-in-init

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem: http://ideone.com/nIPim9

Comment: Interesting, @Robᵩ. Seems like overriding `__new__` might be the way to do what I want, but not exactly sure how to make that work yet.

Comment: @Robᵩ perfect, that approach is what I was looking for. TIL about the difference between constructors and initializers in Python. However, I'm still trying to grasp some of this. Like in your example, we construct a `float` in `__new__` but assign its attribute `extra` in `__init__`, which you couldn't normally do to a `float` instance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As float is immutable you have to overwrite `__new__` as well. The following should do what you want:

```
class Foo(float):
    def __new__(self, value, extra):
        return float.__new__(self, value)
    def __init__(self, value, extra):
        float.__init__(value)
        self.extra = extra

foo = Foo(1,2)
print(str(foo))
1.0
print(str(foo.extra))
2
```

See also [Sub-classing float type in Python, fails to catch exception in __init__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936457/sub-classing-float-type-in-python-fails-to-catch-exception-in-init)

Comment: Yes, this is a working approach - thanks! I'm still puzzled by why this is necessary, though. For your `__init__` method, `self` is a `float` not a `Foo`, right? Because we created it via `float.__new__`?

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13534717/204131 points out that `float.__new__` is passed a parameter of `Foo`, so it should create an instance of `Foo` rather than of float.

Answer (score 12):

Both @cgogolin and @qvpham provide working answers. However, I reckon that `float.__init__(value)` within the `__init__` method is irrelevant to the initialization of `Foo`. That is, it does nothing to initialize attributes of `Foo`. As such, it rather causes confusion on the necessity of the operation toward subclassing the `float` type.

Indeed, the solution can be further simplified as follows:

```
In [1]: class Foo(float):
   ...:     def __new__(cls, value, extra):
   ...:        return super().__new__(cls, value)
   ...:     def __init__(self, value, extra):
   ...:        self.extra = extra

In [2]: foo = Foo(1,2)
   ...: print(str(foo))
1.0

In [3]: print(foo.extra)
2
```

Comment: Note: You don't need to cast foo to a str since its __str()__ method is still fine as it would be for a normal float.

Answer (score 3):

the solution of cgogolin is right. it's like so with another immutable classes like int, str, ... But i will write:

```
class Foo(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, extra):
       return super().__new__(cls, value)
    def __init__(self, value, extra):
       float.__init__(value)
       self.extra = extra
```

Comment: where is cgogolin?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without implementing `__init__` at all:

```
class Foo(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, extra):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, value)
        instance.extra = extra
        return instance
```

In use:

```
>>> foo = Foo(1, 2)
>>> print(foo)
1.0
>>> print(foo.extra)
2
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in that way you're leaving in inheritance the same awkward subclassing.

Comment: @NunoAndré I'm not sure what you mean by that; can you expand a little? Is that specific to *this* answer?

Comment: Of course, I've elaborated it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023077/3775493)

Comment: One downside of this solution is that tools like pylint will complain that extra is not a member of instances of Foo.

Answer (score 1):

While you can handle initialization in the `__new__` method, because it's always called before `__init__` (or even instead of, if `__new__`'s returned object is other than an instance of the class), it's best practice decoupling object initizalization in `__init__` and leaving `__new__` only for object creation.

For instance, in that way you would be able to subclass `Foo`. (Furthermore, passing `*args, **kwargs` to `__new__` will allow the subclass have any number of positional or named arguments.)

```py
class Foo(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, value, extra):
        self.extra = extra

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, value, extra, more):
        super().__init__(value, extra)
        self.more = more
```

However, if you handle initialization in `__new__` you will inherit `object`'s `__init__` which hasn't more arguments than the instance itself. And you won't be able to subclass it by the common way.

```py
class Bar(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, extra):
        self = super().__new__(cls, value)
        self.extra = extra
        return self

class SubBar(Bar):
    def __init__(self, value, extra):
        super().__init__(value, extra)
```

```py
>>> sub_bar = SubBar(1, 2)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Comment: The value of Foo is never initialized in this solution (if one could simply set it in `__init__` then there would not be any need to use `__new__` to begin width).

Comment: Fixed, good catch. That's exactly the problem that I tried to show. `float` is a C primitive type, so it doesn't make sense for it to accept variadic arguments, but doing this when subclassing avoids having to redefine `__new__` for subsequent subclassing.