# How to correctly initialise a subclass of dict with extra arguments in its constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, subclass

Using a [similar approach to a previous question about subclassing a float class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943789/python-can-a-subclass-of-float-take-extra-arguments-in-its-constructor) yields no keys in the dict. For example:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __new__(cls, value, extra):
        return super().__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, value, extra):
        dict.__init__(value)
        self.extra = extra
```

Running `Foo({'a':1}, 1).keys()` returns empty dict keys `dict_keys([])`.

How to correctly subclass a dict with extra arguments in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
dict.__init__(value)
```

To:

```
dict.__init__(self, value)
```

Also consider composition instead of inheritance, because you're breaking away from the API of `dict` here (see [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).